# Jasper Report JAVA swing

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report using java swing that is able to print the data that I have on my SQL database, I found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq7ZsuQZM_w) after I googled my problem and I follow the step-by-step tutorial, everything goes smooth and no error occured, at first it seems fine but after I put these codes (that will generate the report that I want) :

```
public void reportviewer() {
            try{
            String report = "C:\\Users\\cleanfuel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\StringManipulation\\src\\stringmanipulation\\report1.jrxml";
            JasperReport jasp_report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
            JasperPrint jasp_print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasp_report, null, con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasp_print);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {System.out.print(e);}
        }enter code here
```

After I run the program and clicking the buttong report, an error occured and print this :

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this one? Did my I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's just `log4j` complaining that there are no appenders for it to output it's output to.

Unless you are really concerned about the output from Jasper Reports code, you don't need to worry about it to much.

If you want a quick fix, you could add the following to you code before you execute anything else.

```
PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout("[%-5p] %C.%M:%L: %m%n");
ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender(pl);
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
```

It will basically add a console appender that will send the output to the console.

Take a look at [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for more details.

**Updated with example**

```
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout("[%-5p] %C.%M:%L: %m%n");
        ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender(pl);
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
        // The rest of your code...
    }
}
```

Comment: sir @MadProgrammer I'm not familiar with the codes that you've gave to me, and I don't know where to put that 3 lines of codes because I tried puttin them in my codes and an error occurred.

Comment: Do as @Jugal mentioned above. If you are not aware of what Java classpath is refer this tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: @CrystalMaiden First of all, make sure you have the `log4j` jar within you applications classpath (seen as Jasper is providing you with a nice warning, I assume you have).  Add the above code at the start of your `main` method.  Don't forget to include the required imports

Comment: where do I find that log4j.jar? Is it downloadable?

Comment: You can get it from [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html), but as I said, your probably already have it, otherwise Jasper Reports wouldn't have run at all

Comment: I add the log4j.jar that I have on my folder, but there still an error in this line : import org.apache.log4j.Logger; why is that sir MadProgrammer?

Comment: I add the jar that I downloaded from the link that you gave to me, still the line import org.apache.log4j.Logger; have an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28079/discussion-between-crystal-maiden-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: sir @MadProgrammer I'm currently using Netbeans IDE 7.1.1

Comment: Expand the project node so that the `Source Packages` and `Libraries` nodes are visible.  Right click the `Libraries` node and select `Add Jar/Folder...`, browse to where you download the log4j*.jar a select, select `Okay`.  You may need to do a clean build

Comment: Delete the imports and use ctrl+shift+I to "fix the imports"

Comment: Also make sure you've unzipped the file you downloaded.  The Zip file is not the library jar that you need, it contains it

Comment: I Deleted the imports and used the command that you gave, it pop-up something and I accept it, after that I run the program. It loads a lot of things (which kinda makes me excite) but still it says "The documents has no page/s"

Comment: I already unzipped the file sir, and after I add it to library jar it shows me only one which is the log4j.jar, and I add it.

Comment: At least we got the log4j issue out of the way, the no-pages issues may require another question

Comment: oh ok, then I will upvoted your answer thanks for helping me out sir @MadProgrammer and I learn new things, that ctrl+shift+I. thanks! I'll post the new question right away.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `log4j.properties` and put it in your classpath:

```
#
# connector logging configuration
#
# From most to least verbose: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, OFF
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{1}] - %m%n
```

Comment: sir @Jugal Shah , how to do that? can you teach me how to it?